# Dropping first row of CSV if condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I'm building an application and a part of it is downloading a csv file which is present in GCP Storage.

I use this function to get the csv, notice, it is downloaded as a string.

```py
def get_my_csv(run, library):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix="{}/{}".format(run, library))
    for blob in blobs:
        return blob.download_as_string().decode("utf-8")
```

After I get the CSV I parse it into a pandas dataframe like so:

```py
csv_to_use = get_my_csv(run, library)
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_to_use.splitlines())
rows = [r for r in reader]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Now the problem I have is that the people incharge of uploading this CSV file sometimes mess up and I get a CSV that looks like this:

```
Analysis pipeline:,Class II - DPB Full Length,,,,
Local ID,Sample ID,For Code ,For Code Seq,Rev Code Name,Rev Code Seq
4,2949,004F,GGTAGTGTGTATCAGTACATG,004R,GGTAGTGTGTATCAGTACATG
5,1596,005F,GGTAGACACGCATGACACACT,005R,GGTAGACACGCATGACACACT
13,3319,013F,GGTAGACACTGACGTCGCGAC,013R,GGTAGACACTGACGTCGCGAC
```

As you may notice, there is a row before the actual header file. How can I deal with this? Also I'm never sure what they actually may put in the headers. Is there anyway to make my code smart enough to deal with this?

If not smart enough, what logic can I use to drop this row: `Analysis pipeline:,Class II - DPB Full Length,,,,` and make `Local ID,Sample ID,For Code ,For Code Seq,Rev Code Name,Rev Code Seq` my header?

#### Update

Basically, `For Code ,For Code Seq,Rev Code Name,Rev Code Seq` should always be present in the header. How can I skip until I find this, make this the header and parse the rest?

Comment: Will the first column label always be "Local ID"? You could check whether that's at the start of the row, and if not, discard it and check the next row. Otherwise it might be better to find the row with numbers, then start from one row before it.

Comment: Yes. The actual header's first row should always be "Local ID". How can I skip until I find "Local ID"?

Comment: Does the string input of unwanted row also contain correct amount of columns as the csv ( `,,,,` ) before you read it into pandas. Or is it just some string? Would be nice to get the raw input example can be snip of `get_my_csv(run, library)` return.

Comment: @DominicD It'll either be "Local ID" or "Code UID". That's not very helpful. But the header should always include `For Code ,For Code Seq,Rev Code Name,Rev Code Seq` How do I look for this and make that the header?

Comment: @A.Bergen The one I've pasted is the raw CSV. It does include (`,,,,`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the first field of the first data row is numeric, and that the actual header is just the previous one.

I would do:

```
import io
import re
...

numeric = re.compile(r'\d+$')                 # a regex to match a numeric field
csv_to_use = get_my_csv(run, library)
reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(csv_to_use))
rows = list(reader)

# search first data row:
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    if numeric.match(row[0]):
        break
if i == 0: i=1                    # ensure at least a header row...

# build the dataframe
df = df.DataFrame(rows[i:], columns=rows[i-1])
```

---

If you want to filter any white space in the headers, just replace the last line with:

```
df = df.DataFrame(rows[i:], columns=[r.replace(' ', '') for r in rows[i-1]])
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is perfect!

Comment: Is there anyway to deal with whitespaces in the headers?

Comment: @DuDoff: Probably. What do you want to do with them? Strip the initial and trailing spaces, or remove (or replace with a non blank character) any space in a header field?

Comment: Remove any whitespace.

Comment: `LocalID SampleID ForBarcodeName     ForBarcodeSequence RevBarcodeName     RevBarcodeSequence` That removes all spaces.

Comment: I replaced it with `r.strip()` and I think it works. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic approach checking for what you said should always be in the column headings.

```py
csv_to_use = get_my_csv(run, library)
i = 0
for i, row in enumerate(csv_to_use.splitlines()):
    row_split = row.split(',')
    broken = False
    for j,label in enumerate(row_split):
        if 'For Code' in label and 'For Code Seq' in row_split[j+1] and 'Rev Code Name' in row_split[j+2] and 'Rev Code Seq' in row_split[j+3]:
            broken = True
            break
    if broken:
        break
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_to_use.splitlines()[i:])
rows = [r for r in reader]
```

Comment: So rows is an `<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>` - Another issue is that there may be spaces in the headers. So `"For Code"` may be `" For Code"` or `"For Code "` or `" For Code "`

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Dominic! Serge's answer works beautifully!

Comment: No worries. I've edited it to be account for the spaces and check all the labels. But searching for the first row of numbers seems like an easier approach.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'split'` rows is an `OrderedDict` and not a `String`

Comment: Sorry about that. It makes more sense to check the original string and only then call the CSV Reader. I've fixed up this answer for anyone's future reference.

Comment: Man of character!